# Why do these calculations 'stop'?

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy, trigonometry, arbitrary-precision

**Question 1:** If I change *guess* to a integer, for example `guess = 1` then ListPlot already stops at $n=50$. This seems strange to me, any ideas on why this happens? Update, if I change guess to `guess = 1.0` then this doesn't occur. Maybe this has something to do with the loss of precision with Sin?

**Question 2:** Why does the ListPlot stop at $n=512$? Is there something special about the number $4^{512}$?

For reference; to see what is going on I also included the Grid.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
guess = 1.5;
iter = 1000;
n = Table[j, {j, 0, iter}];
y = SetPrecision[Sin[4^n guess]^2, 30];
Grid[Transpose[{n, y}], Frame -> All];
ListPlot[y]
```

Comment: 2^1024, or 4^512 is the maximum machine number (essentially IEEE 64-bit floating point number), and plotting functions use machine numbers in their operation...

Comment: If you use `guess=1`, you aren't even using a floating point, setting it to `1.` makes it use floating point, if you use some other software like `Python` you'll get used to always adding a `.` after an integer.

Comment: @Feyre Ok, but why would that matter in the calculation?

Comment: Because when you don't use floating points the entire calculation is done in fixed points in fewer bits, up to apparentely `4^50`

Comment: Can you change the expression within the `Sin[]` into a recurring function, afterall `Sin[n]=Sin[n+2Pi]`?

Comment: @ImreVégh Probably you should reformulate your question in order to avoid it being closed as a duplicate: your question has nothing to do with plotting but is related to the precision of `Sin` supplied with a very large argument as [showed by @mikado](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119950/280). I don't think this issue was discussed previously.

Answer (score 3):

I offer the following slightly modified version as a better illustration of the problem:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
guess = N[3/2, 300];
iter = 1000;
n = Table[j, {j, 0, iter}];
y = Sin[4^n guess]^2;
Grid[Transpose[{n, y}], Frame -> All]
ListPlot[y]
```

What see from the `Grid` is that at each iteration the number of residual digits of precision decreases - we have 2 less bits available after reduction mod 2 Pi each time.  Eventually there is no precision left and we have a result indistinguishable from zero.

This is slightly hidden in the original version, since the `SetPrecision` function is applied **after** precision has been lost - we neither force Mathematica to work to higher precision nor track it accurately.

Comment: Good catch (+1)! There is a catastrophic loss of precision when `Sin` is supplied with a very large argument. I don't think it was discussed previously.

Comment: @Alexey, trig functions usually do range reduction by adding/subtracting appropriate multiples of the period; for a large enough argument then, you are subtracting two large numbers just to get something within the fundamental domain.

Comment: I do see this happen with guess as integer, but not with guess as floating point... Then the precision stays 30 until n=512